# docker build caused context canceled

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I found [here](https://bitbucket.org/jason_c_kwan/orthomcl_docker/overview) the below Dockerfile:

```
FROM appcontainers/mysql:debian
MAINTAINER Jason C. Kwan "jason.kwan@wisc.edu"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget cpanminus build-essential libmysqlclient-dev python
RUN wget http://www.micans.org/mcl/src/mcl-latest.tar.gz
RUN tar xvf mcl-latest.tar.gz
RUN cd mcl-* && ./configure && make && make install
RUN wget http://orthomcl.org/common/downloads/software/v2.0/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9.tar.gz
RUN tar xvf orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9.tar.gz
RUN cpanm DBI DBD::mysql
RUN mkdir diamond && cd diamond && wget http://github.com/bbuchfink/diamond/releases/download/v0.9.14/diamond-linux64.tar.gz && tar xvf diamond-linux64.tar.gz
RUN rm *.tar.gz

COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/
COPY run_orthomcl.py /bin/
ENV PATH="/diamond:/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9/bin:${PATH}"
```

It failed to build the container with this command:

```
$ docker build -t orthomcl_docker . 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  95.23kB
Step 1/15 : FROM appcontainers/mysql:debian
debian: Pulling from appcontainers/mysql
e80d11fe101a: Pulling fs layer 
125a38e742bc: Pulling fs layer 
8900111cfb5b: Pulling fs layer 
8d736c21b481: Waiting 
3d0796a1857b: Waiting 
158bbfe64bb1: Waiting 
3e3a4a0e9680: Waiting 
ed389ac8eaad: Waiting 
8c74473c64df: Waiting 
context canceled
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Check your network connectivity. Does a `docker pull  appcontainers/mysql` has problems too?

Comment: Thank you, I tried your command and then my again and it works.

Comment: Maybe some other application locked the files. e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65245078/docker-image-build-context-canceled-error-on-windows-10