# Docker container failing to build from base image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-desktop, dockerhub

When I run `docker-compose build` to build my container using Docker Desktop for Windows, I get the following output:

```
[+] Building 4.3s (6/16)                                                                                 docker:default
 => [web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.dev 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 769B
 => [web internal] load .dockerignore
 => => transferring context: 162B
 => [web internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14.15.4-alpine3.10
 => [web auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
 => CANCELED [web  1/11] FROM docker.io/library/node:14.15.4-alpine3.10@sha256:fe215d05cdde4b7f2a0f546c88a8ddc4f5
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:14.15.4-alpine3.10@sha256:fe215d05cdde4b7f2a0f546c88a8ddc4f5fa280a204acdfc2  0.0s
 => => sha256:fe215d05cdde4b7f2a0f546c88a8ddc4f5fa280a204acdfc2383afe901fd6d84 1.43kB / 1.43kB
 => => sha256:3c1278b4775e0531a87c5f59e281e9fd3e9415510f736f6cb7b853a18f733c65 1.16kB / 1.16kB
 => => sha256:1d5f426329f6457972282c871eeae61741de2103bdb13200f3cff390d70f1734 6.73kB / 6.73kB
 => => sha256:21c83c5242199776c232920ddb58cfa2a46b17e42ed831ca9001c8dbc532d22d 0B / 2.80MB
 => => sha256:183201ed1f3fde3d0aa37b312d28e31b6129f0ab073fadb40f002bf3bac7e096 0B / 35.65MB
 => => sha256:61208a7901b0da939053e657b8b0a56fda12331176c5bbe510aa76395c9208fc 0B / 2.24MB
 => CANCELED [web internal] load build context
 => => transferring context: 6.54MB
failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled
```

Dockerfile:

```
# build environment
FROM node:14.15.4-alpine3.10 as build

ARG SSH_PRV_KEY

RUN apk update && \
    apk add git && \
    apk add openssh

# Authorize SSH Host
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /root/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan -t rsa bitbucket.org > /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# Add the keys and set permissions
RUN echo "$SSH_PRV_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

ENV PATH /code/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV PORT=5000
ENV REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV='development'

COPY . ./
# RUN npm ci --silent

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

.dockerignore

```
.DS_Store
**/.DS_Store

.dockerignore
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml

.git
.gitignore

.idea/
.vscode

.env

npm-debug.log
```

This causes the build to fail.

I'm not sure how to debug this as I'm not very familiar with Docker. My internet connection seems to be fine and it always fails at the same step no matter how many times I run it. So far, I've tried the following:

- Reinstalling Docker Desktop
- Restarting my dev machine.
- Uninstalling Android Studio
- The Clean / Purge data option in the Troubleshooting menu.
- The Reset to factory defaults option.
- Disabling my firewall.
- Closing everything but Docker + PowerShell and running the command again.
- Running the drive error checker tool in Windows and there were no errors.
- Adding the `--no-cache` flag to the build command.
- Running `docker-compose build --no-cache` in an administrative Command Prompt.
- Uncheck Experimental features in Docker Desktop.
- Check for updates.
- Checking `.git` was added to the `.dockerignore` file.
- Checking I'm not on a metered connection.
- Logging in with `docker login`.
- Logging out and then in again with `docker logout` and `docker login`.

Comment: Do you have any IDEs open while this happens? I see reports of JetBrains IDEs and R Studio causing this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65245078/docker-image-build-context-canceled-error-on-windows-10
Additionally there is a mention of some docker versions working better than others.

Comment: Hi @jolammi - I don't have R Studio installed. I do have Android Studio, but it's not open. Do you know which Docker versions are supposed to be better?

Comment: It seems that I misread the comments and the docker version trick was three years old - sorry for that. Is there a possibility that Android Studio is still running in the background, or some other software is using the files in the background? Could you share a bit of your directory structure and Dockerfile you could be helped better?

Comment: Also probably worth to check the answers in the linked article and see if any of those apply to your case.

Comment: @jolammi - I've now completely uninstalled Android Studio. It doesn't seem to have made a difference. I don't know that anything else is accessing the files. I've included the `Dockerfile` above. Directory structure is pretty standard for a React app. The project folder is stored in a folder on my Desktop. My React code is in a folder called `src`, some `public` files, `node_modules`, `nginx` folder for storing nginx config, `codebuild` for storing AWS config, `build` folder for storing the built bundle.

Comment: @jolammi - I've tried all of the suggestion solutions in that thread.

Comment: can you even `docker pull docker.io/library/node:14.15.4-alpine3.10`?

Comment: @SiHa - Seems to already be installed. If I delete and try pulling again, it's downloading fine.

Comment: Please add your .dockerignore into the question. If you copy (not move) the project files into another directory, does that make a difference? Also try a different Node image.

Comment: Also try to find the limiting conditions for this problem. Is it a certain project or do all images fail to build? Is there something similar in the dockerfiles which fail to build? If you comment out things from the dockerfile, which is the pivot point where it begins to work?

Comment: @jolammi - I've included the `.dockerignore` file above. Copying the files to another folder didn't help. I'll try some of the stuff you've suggested, but might take some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A coworker of mine was able to solve this issue by downgrading Docker from 4.24.1 back to 4.22.0 and doing a full system reset afterwards (not sure if that was necessary, you could try just the downgrade first).

This was a Windows-specific issue; other people with Docker Desktop for Mac did not encounter this.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Interesting. I wonder if there is a bug report filed about this?

Comment: I haven't had time to look into this but if you do, I'd encourage it! It seems version 4.23.0 is the one where this broke. And: this only happened with certain projects' Dockerfiles, not all of them. We've not been able to narrow down why it happened on the ones it did.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I'm experiencing, but in other projects the build fails at different stages and there's no clear explanation why.